# The tree loses its children, it only remembers the latest. Huffman

Tags: c++

I have a problem, because I'm writing a simplified version of huffman, the program reads a sequence of lowercase letters and creates codes for them. When I want to check out a tree for two roots only.

**Input**

> abbceeeddfff

**Output**

> 1 1 2 3 5 12 7 4 2 2 3 
>   The order doesn't matter, I just want the values out of the tree

[image]

[image]

Code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<vector>
#include<string.h>
#include<queue>
using namespace std;


struct characters
{
    char a;
    int likehood;
    characters *left, *right;
};



struct characters_comparsion
{
    bool operator() (const characters &first, const characters &second)
    {
        if(first.likehood > second.likehood) return true;

        if(first.likehood < second.likehood) return false;

        return false;
    }
};

void print (characters* root)
{

    if(root->left!=NULL)
    {
        print(root->left);

    }

    cout<<root->likehood<<" ";

    if(root->right!=NULL)
    {
        print(root->right);
    }
}

struct characters Huffman(priority_queue<characters, vector<characters>, characters_comparsion> Q)
{

    characters X,Y,*Z,m;
    unsigned long n;

    n = Q.size();


    for(int i=1; i<n-1; i++)
    {
        Z = new characters();
        Z->left = Z->right = NULL;
        X = Q.top();
        Q.pop();

        Y = Q.top();
        Q.pop();

        Z->left = &X;
        Z->right = &Y;
        Z->likehood = X.likehood + Y.likehood;

        Q.push(*Z);

    }

    print(Z);

    return *Z;
}



int main()
{

    vector<characters> how_many_times;
    how_many_times.reserve(26);
    string C="abcdefghijklmnoprqestuvwxyz", rows="abbceeeddfff";
    struct characters *w;
    priority_queue<characters, vector<characters>, characters_comparsion> Q;

    for(int i=0; i<26; i++)
    {
        how_many_times[i].a = C[i];
        how_many_times[i].likehood=0;
        how_many_times[i].left = NULL;
        how_many_times[i].right = NULL;
    }

   /* getline(cin, rows);*/

    unsigned long length = rows.length();

    for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<26; j++)
        {
            if(how_many_times[j].a==rows[i])
            {
                how_many_times[j].likehood++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    for(int i=0; i<26; i++)
    {
        if(how_many_times[i].likehood!=0)
        {
            Q.push(how_many_times[i]);
        }
    }


    *w = Huffman(Q);
    print(w);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: `struct characters *w;` then nothing is done with `w` until `*w = Huffman(Q);`. Sit down with [your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) and talk that through.

Comment: `Z = new characters();` looks like it's being leaked.

Answer (score 0):

The Huffman tree is made up of pointers to automatically allocated local variables.

```
{
    Z = new characters(); // dynamically allocated
    Z->left = Z->right = NULL;
    X = Q.top(); // local copy of data from Q
    Q.pop();

    Y = Q.top(); // local copy of data from Q
    Q.pop();

    Z->left = &X; // storing pointer to local variable
    Z->right = &Y; // storing pointer to local variable
    Z->likehood = X.likehood + Y.likehood;

    Q.push(*Z); // storing copy of object at Z in `vector`
} //Z leaked, local variables go out of scope. Stored pointers to local variables 
  // rendered invalid.
```

Solution:

More dynamic allocation! Store `characters` pointers in `Q` throughout. Don't forget to delete them all at the end. You may find [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) helpful managing the tree.

Comment: don't understand, if I don't take the elements out of the queue, only the initial values are written out

Comment: @Daim123 Been years since I've messed with Huffman coding, but what you're trying to do with the queue is familiar. You probably have the algorithm's steps right, but the way you're storing the data the algorithm is using is incorrect. `Z->left = &X;` fails because `X` is an automatic variable at block scope. At the end of the block `X` goes out of scope and the pointer no longer points to a valid.object, You need to ensure that object remains valid. The easiest way to do that is a `priority_queue` of `characters *`.